# Beckhoff: AddDeviceNotification

Tags: c#, twincat

I have a problem with Beckhoff ADS. I have created a simple project:

```
private const int CONST_num_notification = 1;
private const int CONST_ms_cycleTime = 1;   //ms
private const int CONST_ms_maxDelay = 3000;   //ms

TcAdsClient pAdsClient;
pAdsClient = new TcAdsClient();
pAdsClient.Synchronize = false;
/******CONNECT*/
pAdsClient.Connect(pNetID, pPort);
/**************/   

pHConnect = new int[CONST_num_notification];
pDataStream = new AdsStream();      
pHConnect[0] = pAdsClient.AddDeviceNotification("MAIN.SyncPLCtoHMI", pDataStream, 0, 2, AdsTransMode.OnChange, CONST_ms_cycleTime, CONST_ms_maxDelay, null);   

pAdsClient.AdsNotification += pAdsClient_AdsNotification;
```

So, whene MAIN.SyncPLCtoHMI changes, I should receive a notification, but this MAIN.SyncPLCtoHMI changes every 20ms (and it is right and I want this time) but Windows some times blocks this notification...

What can I do?, There's an alternative mode for setting Windows or ADS?

Comment: The idea of making HMI to sync every 20 ms is a non sense. It's better to change the point of view of your HMI which isn't a real time system

Answer (score 2):

You use a PLC programm and link the variables to a task, right?

Can you please tell us how you configured your task? I guess the task cycle time in twincat is too large. The default value is round about 1ms, if you didnt change it.

The cycle time you use as parameter within your method AddDeviceNotification has no influence on this, when your task is slower. You need to configure the task in twincat first.

Two more Info:

If you run your application locally this should be sufficient (NetID is not needed).

```
pAdsClient.Connect(pPort);
```

I would instanciate the AdsStream with a length. An example
if your Value is a WORD:

```
private AdsStream pDataStream = new AdsStream(sizeof(Int16));
```

I hope I could help.